# Encoded Polygon limit with Google Maps Image API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygons

I'm trying to get images with the [Google Maps Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index) of polygons representing areas of the UK. For some reason the imaging doesn't work when the polygon has too many coordinates and I can't find out why.

I'm encoding the polygons into the url as [described here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index#EncodedPolylines) using the [rails polylines gem](https://github.com/joshuaclayton/polylines).

A polygon of Camden in London is made with the following coordinates:

```
coords = [[-0.120544, 51.531198], [-0.127403, 51.533038], [-0.12757, 51.544915], [-0.139614, 51.558465], [-0.140785, 51.56867], [-0.172904, 51.574357], [-0.200339, 51.553112], [-0.215729, 51.553112], [-0.210376, 51.545751], [-0.190134, 51.532201], [-0.179428, 51.537889], [-0.172067, 51.536049], [-0.155841, 51.535213], [-0.150655, 51.526012], [-0.135097, 51.517648], [-0.131585, 51.512295], [-0.12389, 51.516979], [-0.114856, 51.516979], [-0.108834, 51.521161]]
```

Which when used with the gem produces an encoded string:

```
enc = Polylines::Encoder.encode_points(coords)
-> jpV_uoyHzi@oJ`@giAfjAusAjFw~@tgEqb@njDxcCd_B?m`@~l@q}BtsA{aAqb@_m@nJmdBfDk_@nx@g`Bfs@}Tl`@co@g\\mw@?ud@cY
```

Then when placed in the [API url doesn't produce a polygon (click here)](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?scale=2&size=1000x1000&sensor=false&style=feature%3alandscape%7Celement%3aall%7Csaturation%3a-100%7Clightness:65%7Cvisibility%3aon%7C&style=feature%3apoi%7Celement%3aall%7Csaturation%3a-100%7Clightness:51%7Cvisibility%3asimplified%7C&style=feature%3aroad.highway%7Celement%3aall%7Csaturation%3a-100%7Cvisibility%3asimplified%7C&style=feature%3aroad.arterial%7Celement%3aall%7Csaturation%3a-100%7Clightness:30%7Cvisibility%3aon%7C&style=feature%3aroad.local%7Celement%3aall%7Csaturation%3a-100%7Clightness:40%7Cvisibility%3aon%7C&style=feature%3atransit%7Celement%3aall%7Csaturation%3a-100%7Cvisibility%3asimplified%7C&style=feature%3aadministrative.province%7Celement%3aall%7Cvisibility%3aoff%7C&style=feature%3awater%7Celement%3alabels%7Cvisibility%3aon%7Clightness%3a-25%7Csaturation%3a-100%7C&style=feature%3awater%7Celement%3ageometry%7Chue:0xffff00%7Clightness%3a-25%7Csaturation%3a-97%7C&path=color:0044ff%7Cweight:1%7Cfillcolor%3ablue%7Cenc%3ajpV_uoyHzi@oJ%60@giAfjAusAjFw~@tgEqb@njDxcCd_B?m%60@~l@q%7DBtsA%7BaAqb@_m@nJmdBfDk_@nx@g%60Bfs@%7DTl%60@co@g%5C%5Cmw@?ud@cY).

But if I cut the coordinates in half, limiting the coordinates, [it does produce a polygon](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?scale=2&size=1000x1000&sensor=false&style=feature%3alandscape%7Celement%3aall%7Csaturation%3a-100%7Clightness:65%7Cvisibility%3aon%7C&style=feature%3apoi%7Celement%3aall%7Csaturation%3a-100%7Clightness:51%7Cvisibility%3asimplified%7C&style=feature%3aroad.highway%7Celement%3aall%7Csaturation%3a-100%7Cvisibility%3asimplified%7C&style=feature%3aroad.arterial%7Celement%3aall%7Csaturation%3a-100%7Clightness:30%7Cvisibility%3aon%7C&style=feature%3aroad.local%7Celement%3aall%7Csaturation%3a-100%7Clightness:40%7Cvisibility%3aon%7C&style=feature%3atransit%7Celement%3aall%7Csaturation%3a-100%7Cvisibility%3asimplified%7C&style=feature%3aadministrative.province%7Celement%3aall%7Cvisibility%3aoff%7C&style=feature%3awater%7Celement%3alabels%7Cvisibility%3aon%7Clightness%3a-25%7Csaturation%3a-100%7C&style=feature%3awater%7Celement%3ageometry%7Chue:0xffff00%7Clightness%3a-25%7Csaturation%3a-97%7C&path=color:0044ff%7Cweight:1%7Cfillcolor%3ablue%7Cenc%3a_uoyHjpVoJzi@giA%60@usAfjAw~@jFqb@tgExcCnjD?d_B).

```
enc = Polylines::Encoder.encode_points([[51.531198, -0.120544], [51.533038, -0.127403], [51.544915, -0.12757], [51.558465, -0.139614], [51.56867, -0.140785], [51.574357, -0.172904], [51.553112, -0.200339], [51.553112, -0.215729]])
-> _uoyHjpVoJzi@giA`@usAfjAw~@jFqb@tgExcCnjD?d_B
```

Any ideas why? I can't find any documented limits in this API with regards to encoded polygons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to urlencode the encode path:

Important: *The discussion of URL parameters below use examples that for clarity are given in their pre-escaping form. **Before sending any request to the API, its parameters should be properly URL encoded**. For example, many parameters use a pipe character (|) as a separator, which should be encoded as %7C in the final URL, as in the quick example at the top of this document*.

urlencoded path in URL: [http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?scale=2&size=1000x1000&sensor=false&path=color:0044ff|weight:1|fillcolor%3ablue|enc:jpV_uoyHzi%40oJ%60%40giAfjAusAjFw~%40tgEqb%40njDxcCd_B%3Fm%60%40~l%40q}BtsA{aAqb%40_m%40nJmdBfDk_%40nx%40g%60Bfs%40}Tl%60%40co%40g\mw%40%3Fud%40cY](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?scale=2&size=1000x1000&sensor=false&path=color:0044ff%7Cweight:1%7Cfillcolor%3ablue%7Cenc%3ajpV_uoyHzi@oJ%60@giAfjAusAjFw~@tgEqb@njDxcCd_B?m%60@~l@q%7DBtsA%7BaAqb@_m@nJmdBfDk_@nx@g%60Bfs@%7DTl%60@co@g%5Cmw@?ud@cY)

Don't be confused because of the blue background. You've switched lat and lng in `coords`, the polygon is not placed in london, it's somewhere in the ocean between somalia and seychelles.

**I guess the desired result should be this:**

[`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?scale=2&size=1000x1000&sensor=false&style=feature%3Alandscape%7Celement%3Aall%7Csaturation%3A-100%7Clightness%3A65%7Cvisibility%3Aon%7C&style=feature%3Apoi%7Celement%3Aall%7Csaturation%3A-100%7Clightness%3A51%7Cvisibility%3Asimplified%7C&style=feature%3Aroad.highway%7Celement%3Aall%7Csaturation%3A-100%7Cvisibility%3Asimplified%7C&style=feature%3Aroad.arterial%7Celement%3Aall%7Csaturation%3A-100%7Clightness%3A30%7Cvisibility%3Aon%7C&style=feature%3Aroad.local%7Celement%3Aall%7Csaturation%3A-100%7Clightness%3A40%7Cvisibility%3Aon%7C&style=feature%3Atransit%7Celement%3Aall%7Csaturation%3A-100%7Cvisibility%3Asimplified%7C&style=feature%3Aadministrative.province%7Celement%3Aall%7Cvisibility%3Aoff%7C&style=feature%3Awater%7Celement%3Alabels%7Cvisibility%3Aon%7Clightness%3A-25%7Csaturation%3A-100%7C&style=feature%3Awater%7Celement%3Ageometry%7Chue%3A0xffff00%7Clightness%3A-25%7Csaturation%3A-97%7C&path=color%3A0044ff%7Cweight%3A1%7Cfillcolor%3Ablue%7Cenc%3A_uoyHjpVoJzi%40giA%60%40usAfjAw~%40jFqb%40tgExcCnjD%3Fd_B~l%40m%60%40tsAq%7DBqb%40%7BaAnJ_m%40fDmdBnx%40k_%40fs%40g%60Bl%60%40%7DTg%5Cco%40%3Fmw%40cYud%40`](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?scale=2&size=1000x1000&sensor=false&style=feature%3alandscape%7Celement%3aall%7Csaturation%3a-100%7Clightness:65%7Cvisibility%3aon%7C&style=feature%3apoi%7Celement%3aall%7Csaturation%3a-100%7Clightness:51%7Cvisibility%3asimplified%7C&style=feature%3aroad.highway%7Celement%3aall%7Csaturation%3a-100%7Cvisibility%3asimplified%7C&style=feature%3aroad.arterial%7Celement%3aall%7Csaturation%3a-100%7Clightness:30%7Cvisibility%3aon%7C&style=feature%3aroad.local%7Celement%3aall%7Csaturation%3a-100%7Clightness:40%7Cvisibility%3aon%7C&style=feature%3atransit%7Celement%3aall%7Csaturation%3a-100%7Cvisibility%3asimplified%7C&style=feature%3aadministrative.province%7Celement%3aall%7Cvisibility%3aoff%7C&style=feature%3awater%7Celement%3alabels%7Cvisibility%3aon%7Clightness%3a-25%7Csaturation%3a-100%7C&style=feature%3awater%7Celement%3ageometry%7Chue:0xffff00%7Clightness%3a-25%7Csaturation%3a-97%7C&path=color:0044ff%7Cweight:1%7Cfillcolor%3ablue%7Cenc%3a_uoyHjpVoJzi@giA%60@usAfjAw~@jFqb@tgExcCnjD?d_B~l@m%60@tsAq%7DBqb@%7BaAnJ_m@fDmdBnx@k_@fs@g%60Bl%60@%7DTg%5Cco@?mw@cYud@)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it now. Strangely the coordinates are switched, But I'm not having problems with them, I didn't see the ocean in Somalia, it showed me the whole world. In the first static maps link in my question do you see the ocean in Somalia?

Comment: Thanks! It was the urlencode, such a dumb mistake. And the coords are switched but I have no idea how I got London in the URLs in my question... odd.

Comment: I've added the really "clean" URL above.

Comment: Thanks! The reason why I think I managed to get London in my question was because one of the sets of coordinates are actually in the right order. I was switching them momentarily when I was debugging to see if it made a difference. But I think they were actually already switched in the datasource, I'm not 100% sure because I'm not that experienced with mapping, but you can see them here -> https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1IIoHtB9GZK7KuPP7_rP0KdDXWVOfyM1aKBuyPG0#map:id=3

Comment: How did you export the data from the fusiontable?

Comment: I downloaded it as a .csv, opened it in the terminal and stored the data from there. I'm going to switch all the coordinates now, luckily its not too work :)

Comment: The geometry is stored inside the FusionTable in KML-format(which will also be returned when you export it as CSV) . In KML the order of the details for a `coordinate` is **`longitude,latitude[,altitude]`** while the maps-API's for a `LatLng` expect **`latitude,longitude`** ...so you must switch the first 2 floats (and ommit the `altitude`, when present)

Comment: Interesting.. I wonder why they store the longitude first in KML format.. I think I have some research to do. Thank you so much, you were exceptionally helpful :)

Comment: KML is a standardized format for the storage of geometric data. Inside the Table it's possible to store complex geometries, not only points. KML is suitable to 1. store these data 2. import/export the data